# Why is a binary tree is preferable to an array of values that has been sorted?

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, tree

Why is a binary tree is preferable to an array of values that has been sorted?

In either case, finding a given key value (by traversing a binary tree, or by performing a binary search on a sorted array) carries a time complexity of O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

A binary tree is preferable for insertions/deletions which can be done in time complexity of O(log n). Whereas, insertions/deletions in case of arrays would be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Binary Tree -  A tree in which each node has at most two children, which are referred to as the left child and the right child.

Binary Search Tree - A binary tree in which each node has a comparable key and which satisfies the restriction that the key in any node is larger than the keys in all nodes in that node's left sub-tree and smaller than the keys in all nodes in that node's right sub-tree.

You are probably referring to a Binary Search Tree. The average time complexity is O(log n) and the worst case time complexity is O(n) for finding an element in a binary search tree implemented using a linked list. The worst case is the case where the tree is completely unbalanced. On the other hand, the worst case time complexity for finding an element in a sorted array is O(log n). Hence, it is not true that a binary search tree is preferred to a sorted array for finding a given value.

Your requirements will decide what data structure is preferable.

- Binary Search Tree implemented using a linked list would be preferable when contiguous free memory is scarce.
- Insertions are faster in a binary search tree.
- Directly accessing an element has a time complexity of O(log n) in a binary search tree implemented using a linked list and O(1) in a sorted array. Note that the worst case would be O(n) for a binary search tree. In this case, the binary search tree would be completely unbalanced.

Comment: The question is about finding the element in both data structure, not to directly access an element.

Comment: In that case, you should frame your question in a different manner.